# Do sodastream PET bottles have normal 28mm threaded caps?

Tags: soda, carbonation

The question pretty much says it all. So far all of the bottles I have found have breaks in the threads which I've been told makes homemade sodas go flat faster. I was considering picking up some sodastream bottles if standard caps fit them since I would assume they do not have the breaks in the threading.

The ultimate goal is to keep homemade sodas from going fizzy as fast as most commercially available bottles (1L, 2L, 3L, 12oz, 16oz, 20oz, 24oz) have small breaks in the threading to make drinks go flat faster (to keep you going out and buying more soda).

So the question is, do sodastream bottles use standard sized caps (28mm)?

Comment: Can you give an example of Normal 28mm? for comparison.

Comment: Just about any 1L, 2L, 12oz, 16oz, or 20oz bottle will be 28mm. It's the standard size threaded cap.

Comment: This is an engineering question, not a culinary question.

Comment: Really? Because it's necessary to keep food fizzy which is directly related to culinary arts. Your comment is like saying that asking about the proper size for a roaster has nothing to do with cooking.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I think if the title was re-worded this would be considered an equipment question.  To quote yourself, 'the spirit' of the question is to keep the drinks fizzy.

Comment: @MandoMando Me? I am innocent.

Comment: @matthew I'm pretty sure the opening on soda-stream bottles is wider than regular bottles.  The caps feel much bulkier.  If no one else posts, I'll check tonight when I get home.

Comment: @Matthew do you mean to keep homemade sodas from going flat?  Still lost on what you're trying to do.

Comment: That is the goal. We just assembled a home carbonation system, and I'm noticing that my smaller 16oz PET bottles seem to stay carbonated for a few days, while the larger commercially "repurposed" 2L bottles go flat in about a day. I was hoping that sodastream's purpose-built bottles are a nice compromise (but only if they fit standard 28mm caps). If not I'll have to look into a soda siphon.

Comment: Well their bottles are about 1L and come with their own cap (quite sure different size than commercial soft drinks).  But they do hold gas nicely.  They do melt in the dishwasher nicely though ;)

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ ok, now it sounds more like an engineering question.

Comment: I think you should ask the question about why your sodas are going flat in a day, as that's the actual problem it sounds like you're having. When the commercial bottler puts it in the commercial bottle it doesn't go flat in a day (or two, or even a year).

Comment: The issue is I know why that happens (it remains sealed and is kept under constant pressure by the CO2). The second that seal is broken, air can enter the bottle. CO2 begins leaking out into that air. The goal is to find a bottle which limits the impact of this. I already know using a smaller bottle helps diminish this issue. Sodastream bottles are readily available, hence asking about them.

Comment: I'm not sure I believe the bit about the broken threads. Soda caps seal on a soft membrane under the cap--the threads have nothing to do with it. As long as the cap threads down securely, the seal is made between the top of the bottle and the inside of the cap, regardless of whether the threads are broken or not.

Comment: For all who are asking, the ultimate question is this: Do sodastream bottles use standard sized (28mm) caps? So far it looks like they do not.

Comment: Matthew, I think everyone understands that the question you've posted is about the caps. But they're also right that that's not the question you should really be asking - your goal is to keep your soda from going flat, so you should really ask about that, not about a specific plan to accomplish it. See [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Matthew, the [homebrew stack exchange](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/) might be able to give good advice about carbonation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the sodastream caps are big enough to fit a standard bottle cap *inside* it entirely. Practically everything about the sodastream is made in a proprietary manner to make sure you use their products as intended and never interchange them with something else (and can only purchase replacement parts from them)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Soda stream caps]

Here's a close up. I don't have any in my personal possession, but by examining the pictures, they do appear to be the normal 1-liter sized cap, used on Pepsi products. I welcome some additions to this answer, if somebody has access to the physical caps.

Answer (score 0):

Having measured the caps recently due to looking for suitable alternatives.
The outer diameter of the sealing cap is 4cm, the bottle' screw neck is 3.5cm.
So a normal pop bottle is too thin to use with sodastream as your probably aware of by now & you can now buy adapters for smaller necked bottles on ebay & suchlike, however I would not recommend an normal pop bottle being reused as it may explode under pressure due to the plastic being too flexible & previously being carbonated.
If you live in the UK then Asda seem to do a £1, 750ml hard bottle with a 4cm outer cap that seems suitable but I need to go back down & measure the neck.